# programatically made checkbox at run time does not set proper in all screen

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-checkbox

I am fetching checkboxes value from database. and made checkboxes grammatically....It is running fine and checkboxes are made..

actually i am facing a problem is that checkboxes does not look same in all screens...

what should i do for this...?

This is my xml code : -

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my Activity :-

```
 public class Amardeep extends Activity {
 String responseString, success, name, id, pref, per_amout, percentage,
        datediff, dateNo, minpvalue, discountonit, bus_id, bus_type_id,
        str;
 int a;
String[] idsplit, namesplit, prefsplit;
List<String> testArrayList;
LinearLayout llmain;
LinearLayout[] lLayout;
Integer count1 = 0;
Context mContext;
CheckBox cb;
CheckBox[] cbs;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String finalresult, emp_access_name, minredemption, min_redeem;
Integer count = 0;
String data = "";
Button save;
TextView tvo;
EditText mpv, discount, mra;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.amardeep);

    new Homedata1().execute();

    llmain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain);
}

   class Homedata1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Amardeep.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.xyz.in/android_new/checkbox.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bus_id", "B115"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bus_type_id",
                    "BT101"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultStr) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                success = json_data.getString("success");
                id = json_data.getString("id");
                name = json_data.getString("name");
                pref = json_data.getString("pref");

                idsplit = id.split(",");
                a = idsplit.length;
                namesplit = name.split(",");
                prefsplit = pref.split(",");
                testArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(
                        Arrays.asList(prefsplit));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success.equals("1")) {
            int b = (a / 3);
            int c = (a % 3);
            if (c != 0) {
                b = b + 1;
            }
            lLayout = new LinearLayout[b];
            cbs = new CheckBox[a];

            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                int x = 0;
                x = x + (j * 3);
                lLayout[j] = new LinearLayout(Amardeep.this);
                llmain.addView(lLayout[j]);
                for (int i = x; i < x + 3; i++) {
                    cbs[i] = new CheckBox(Amardeep.this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            140, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);                   
                    params.leftMargin = 15;
                    params.topMargin = 10;
                    if ((i + 1) > a) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (testArrayList.contains(idsplit[i])) {

                            cbs[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                            cbs[i].setText(namesplit[i]);
                            cbs[i].setId(i + 1);
                            cbs[i].setChecked(true);
                            count++;
                            result.append(i + 1 + ",");
                            cbs[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            cbs[i].setTextSize(10f);
                            cbs[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
                            cbs[i].setPadding(35, 0, 30, 0);
                            cbs[i].setTag(i + 1);
                            if (count1.equals(1)) {
                                cbs[i].setEnabled(true);
                            } else {
                                cbs[i].setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            lLayout[j].addView(cbs[i]);
                        } else {

                            cbs[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                            cbs[i].setText(namesplit[i]);
                            cbs[i].setId(i + 1);
                            cbs[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            cbs[i].setTextSize(10f);
                            cbs[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
                            cbs[i].setPadding(35, 0, 30, 0);
                            cbs[i].setTag(i + 1);
                            if ((count1.equals(1))) {
                                cbs[i].setEnabled(true);
                            } else {
                                cbs[i].setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            lLayout[j].addView(cbs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Data empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? Are you asking how to change the view for different screen sizes?

Comment: Yes..i exactly want this solution

Comment: The application is working properly but when i am running on multiple screens the checkboxes are not appearing properly.... i want proper setting and same appearance of the checkboxes in all screens.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) are the android docs for creating different layouts for different screen sizes. What you should see in your directory structure is something like this

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

For each screen size you will make a different XML layout file. You can do the same thing for different drawable files if you are creating your check box using XML.

Edit

If you want to create your own custom checkbox you need to make a checkbox class and extend Checkbox. From there you can set drawables and fonts.

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        sharedConstrutor(context);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstrutor(context);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstrutor(context);
    }

    public void sharedConstrutor(Context context) {
        this.mContext=context;
        if(!isInEditMode())
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/MuseoSans_300.ttf"));

//set other values as needed here.
    }
}
```

Edit

And I think you should add the checkbox to the LinearLayout using the correct LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 123;
li.addView(cb, params);
```

Comment: I am creating my checkbox using java code(programatically)